# Vulkan: Framebuffer larger than Image dimensions

Tags: vulkan

This question primarily relates to the dimension parameters (*width*, *height*, and *layers*) in the structure [*VkFramebufferCreateInfo*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkFramebufferCreateInfo).

### The actual question:

In the case that one or more of the [*VkImageViews*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#resources-image-views), used in creating a [*VkFrameBuffer*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#_framebuffers), has dimensions that are larger than those specified in the [*VkFramebufferCreateInfo*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#VkFramebufferCreateInfo) used to create the [*VkFrameBuffer*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#_framebuffers), how does one control which part of that [*VkImageView*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#resources-image-views) is used during a render pass instance?

### Alternatively worded question:

I am basically asking in the case that the image is larger (not the same dimensions) than the framebuffer, what defines which part of the image is used (read/write)?

### Some Details:

The specification states this is a valid situation (I have seen many people state the attachments used by a framebuffer must match the dimensions of the framebuffer itself, but I can't find support for this in the specification):

> Each element of pAttachments must have dimensions at least as large as the corresponding framebuffer dimension.

I want to be clear, that I understand that if I just wanted to draw to part of an image I can use a framebuffer that has the **same** dimensions as the image, and use [viewports](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#vertexpostproc-viewport) and [scissors](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#fragops-scissor). But scissors and viewports are defined relative to the framebuffer's (0,0) as far as I can tell from the spec, although it is not clear to me.

I'm asking this question to help my understand of the framebuffer as I am certain I have misunderstood something. I feel it may well be the case that (x,y) in framebuffer space, is always (x,y) in image space (As in there is no way of controlling which part of the *VkImageView* is used).

I have been stuck on this for quite sometime (~4 days), and have tried both the *Vulkan: Cookbook* and the *Vulkan Programming Guide*, and read most of the specification, and searched online.

If the question needs clarification, please ask. I just didn't want to make it overly long.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Well, this is a very interesting question. It indeed looks that there is not control where the framebuffer area starts, relatively to the upper-left corner of images used as framebuffer attachments. You cannot provide upper left corner neither during framebuffer creation, nor during image view creation. Only the whole image is taken into account so I think framebuffer is relative to images' upper-left corners, [0,0] coordinates. The only thing that let's You control it is render area in vkCmdBeginRenderPass() command and setting proper values for viewport and scissor test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to control which part of the image is used by the framebuffer when the framebuffer is smaller than the image. The framebuffer origin always maps to the image origin.

Allowing attachments to be larger than the framebuffer is only meant to allow reusing memory/images/views for several purposes in a frame even when they don't all need the same dimensions. The typical example is reusing a depth buffer (but not it's contents) for several different render passes. You could accomplish the same thing with memory aliasing, but engines that have to support multiple APIs might find it easier to do it this way.

Answer (score 2):

The way to control where you render to is by controlling the viewport. That is, you specify a framebuffer size that's actually big enough to cover the total area of the target images that you may want to render to, and use the viewport transform/scissoring to render to a specific area of those images.

There is no post-viewport transformation that goes from framebuffer space to image space. That would be decidedly redundant, since we already have a post-NDC transform. There's no point in having two of them.

Sure, `VkRenderPassBeginInfo` has the `renderArea` object, but that is more of a promise *from* the user rather than a guarantee for the system:

> The application **must** ensure (using scissor if necessary) that all rendering is contained within the render area, otherwise the pixels outside of the render area become undefined and shader side effects **may** occur for fragments outside the render area.

So basically, the implementation doesn't do anything with `renderArea`. It doesn't set up a transformation or anything; you're just promising that no framebuffer pixels outside of that area will be impacted.

In any case, there's really little point to providing a framebuffer size that's smaller than the images sizes. That sort of thing is more the perview of the `renderArea` than the framebuffer specification.